# how to do versioning in Golang REST API via swaggo?

Tags: go, swagger

To generate swagger documentation I use swaggo (https://github.com/swaggo/swag ). I need to split the documentation into v1 and v2 versions. How can I implement this? Can I do something similar like it's done here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/516 , but only for Go?

Comment: It all depends on how you have set up your project and how far you want to go. 
Lets say you have your controllers for v1 and v2 in separate directories e.g `controllers/vN/...` then you could probably get away with running swaggo generator twice with different `--dir` and `--output` parameters. Each version dir containing the genral-info file with different `Version` etc. 
Then you need to probably alter the handler a bit to allow switching the json source during routing.

Comment: @Crazy Atom Hey did you ever figure out how to make versioning work with Swaggo?